# Prime numbers dividing infinitely many numbers in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

[Here](https://www.math.toronto.edu/%7Eherzig/putnam_nt_oct07.pdf) I found a question:

> Show that every prime not equal to $2$ or $5$ divides infinitely many
> of the numbers $1,11,111,1111,\dots$ etc.

which is partly solved here [Prime numbers divide an element from a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046292/prime-numbers-divide-an-element-from-a-set).

From this the following conjecture seems reasonable:

> Given any finite set $S=\{q_1,\dots,q_k\}$ of $k$ primes, then any
> prime $p\notin S$ divides infinitely many of the numbers
> $a_1,a_2,a_3\dots$, where $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=1+a_n\prod q_i$.

Can this be proved?

Comment: Please don't reapply the conjecture tag to personal conjectures that turn out to be (well-)known results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction $\,a_n = \dfrac{q^n-1}{q-1},\ q = \prod q_i.\,$ [$a_n$ is a divisibility sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/609908/242), i.e.  $\,n\mid m\Rightarrow a_n\mid a_m\,$ so $\,p\mid a_n\mid a_{nk}\Rightarrow p\mid a_{nk}\,$ for all $\,k\in\Bbb N$

Answer (score 2):

Define $Q:=\prod q_i$. When $Q=1$ the result is trivial.

Otherwise, it is clear that $a_n = {\underbrace{11\dots1_Q}_{n\ 1\text{'s}}}=1+Q+Q^2+\dots+Q^{n-1} = \dfrac {Q^n - 1}{Q-1}$.

The rest essentially follows from changing $10$ to $Q$. Details below:

Choose your $p\notin S$.

For $p\nmid (Q-1)$, as by Fermat $p\mid (Q^{k(p-1)}-1)$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$, $p \mid a_{k(p-1)}$ by coprimality.

For $p \mid (Q-1)$, observe that $$a_n = 1+Q+Q^2+\dots+Q^{n-1}\equiv1+1+1^2+\dots +1^{n-1}\equiv n \pmod Q$$ so $a_{kp}\equiv kp\equiv 0 \pmod p$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$.